# Should Games request Audio Focus on Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

I have been [reading](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/index.html) the Android documentation on "Audio Focus", and the best-practices they lay out, but one thing alludes me...

Games need music pretty much the whole time, so it makes sense to request Audio Focus *OnStart*, but this can lead to a bad user experience.

If my App requests Audio Focus, and something is currently playing music already (eg. Samsung Music Player), my request will forcefully stop their music. The only special case I know of is if you request Audio Focus while the user is in a Phone Conversation.

I think what the user *expects* to happen, is if they are not already listening to music (or podcast, or whatever), then the game music should play. However, if they are already listening to their own music, then the game should not play music (but still play sound effects).

This is how things work on Xbox, Windows Phone, PS3, etc.

Is this just how it is on Android? Has anyone come up with a nice work around?

**Note:** I am familiar with `AudioManager.IOnAudioFocusChangeListener`. I am speaking specifically about the initial request for Audio Focus.

Answer (score 0):

The other special case to avoid stopping something from playing when requesting audio focus is to allow it to duck, but that applies to transient loss which isn't what you would be doing. There's no way to know if another app is playing audio unfortunately so you will either take the audio and kill the music or you can not request the audio and hope for the best.

It might be worth prompting the user on launch if they are listening to their own music and if so then your game music will remain silent.